# How can the cycle of creation and destruction be eternal if it relies on manifestations that must have originated from Brahman in the past?

Tags: philosophy, brahman

If everything originated from Brahman, then how could the cycle of creation and destruction be eternal if it relies on Shiva, Vishnu, and Brahma, because all three are physical manifestations that must have originated from Brahman as well. Would this not mean that the cycle of creation and destruction had a beginning?

Comment: the cycles have been without beginning in the past and will be without end in the future. What you are thinking of as physical manifestations have their creation and destruction with each cycle. The Saguna Brahman 'breathes' out its manifestations with each new cycle.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to present Vedic hymns or Upanishad references for this (if those exist)?

Comment: See Brahma Sutras 2.1.36 available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras. Sankaracharya gives a Rig Veda reference in the commentary to this verse.